# CoreData could not fulfill a fault after MOC refreshed - how to solve?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm new to iphone development and have this problem with Core Data.

At the moment my app works as follows:

1. I'm executing a fetch from Core Data and display my list of objects in TableView
2. Detaching new thread, create new MOC for it, as advised,
3. Getting xml, parse it, then clear Core Data and fill it with new data from xml
4. Saving my MOC.

It works fine if user isn't scrolling TableView within saving of MOC, but if he is, I'm getting this error and the application crashes.

Can anyone explain in plain English why it's happening and how can I solve the problem.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution is easy, need just get initially normal objects, not faults from CoreData, using property of request object

like this:

```
//...
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
//...
```

There is no difference in memory allocation (at least I didn't notice it in Tools), but the problem disappears)